# Centralising application name for display

Tags: c#, winforms, constants

One of the products that I am working on has recently been renamed, and since I thought doing the renaming would be a fun exercise with regular expressions I picked up the task.

I have to change the name displayed on all the UI (but not assemblies or registry entries). However I want to make the task simpler for the next guy, if the name ever has to change again. So I was thinking of introducing a constant somewhere for the name to display.

The result is concatenating three strings, for a simple dialogue box that only had one string in the past. This is ugly code.

Is there a better way to accomplish the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can use [Application.ProductName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.productname.aspx)

```
private void PrintProductName() {
    textBox1.Text = "The product name is: " +
       Application.ProductName;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done by displaying the `AssemblyTitle` property from the `AssemblyInfo` class, which seems to be the canonical way. A full documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AssemblyInfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Converning the output in the UI, sooner or later format strings would have to be introduced anyway. In your case, the string would be generated by code

```
string MessageBoxString
    = String.Format("Do you want to quit the app {0}?", AsmInfo.AssemblyTitle));
```

or something similar, where `AsmInfo` is an instance of `AssemblyInfo`.